# *kernel config of xenial kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel, configuration

Where can I look into the default kernel config of the `Xenial` kernel?
I'm particularly interested in the USB Power management configuration including:

- `CONFIG_SUSPEND`
- `CONFIG_HIBERNATION`
- `CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME`
- `CONFIG_PM`  and
- `CONFIG_USB_SUSPEND`

`uname -r` gives me: **4.4.38-l4t-r28.2+g174510d**

Comment: Do you realize there are two kernels supported by 16.04/xenial. The default GA kernel (4.4) and the HWE (4.15) kernel which is also the 18.04 GA kernel. The HWE kernel supported for xenial moved using 16.10/17.04/17.10 before finally settling on what will remain 18.04's GA kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this 16.04 kernel:

```
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ uname -a
Linux DOUG-64 4.4.0-176-generic #206-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:02:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The information you seek is:

```
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ uname -a
Linux DOUG-64 4.4.0-176-generic #206-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:02:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ grep CONFIG_SUSPEND config-4.4.0-176-generic
CONFIG_SUSPEND=y
CONFIG_SUSPEND_FREEZER=y
# CONFIG_SUSPEND_SKIP_SYNC is not set
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ grep CONFIG_HIBERNATION config-4.4.0-176-generic
CONFIG_HIBERNATION=y
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ grep CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME config-4.4.0-176-generic
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ grep CONFIG_PM config-4.4.0-176-generic
CONFIG_PM_STD_PARTITION=""
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP=y
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP_SMP=y
# CONFIG_PM_AUTOSLEEP is not set
CONFIG_PM_WAKELOCKS=y
CONFIG_PM_WAKELOCKS_LIMIT=100
CONFIG_PM_WAKELOCKS_GC=y
CONFIG_PM=y
CONFIG_PM_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_PM_ADVANCED_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_PM_TEST_SUSPEND is not set
CONFIG_PM_SLEEP_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_PM_TRACE=y
CONFIG_PM_TRACE_RTC=y
CONFIG_PM_CLK=y
# CONFIG_PMIC_OPREGION is not set
CONFIG_PMC_ATOM=y
CONFIG_PMBUS=m
CONFIG_PMIC_ADP5520=y
CONFIG_PMIC_DA903X=y
CONFIG_PMIC_DA9052=y
CONFIG_PM_DEVFREQ=y
CONFIG_PM_DEVFREQ_EVENT=y
CONFIG_PM_NOTIFIER_ERROR_INJECT=m
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$ grep CONFIG_USB_SUSPEND config-4.4.0-176-generic
doug@DOUG-64:/boot$
```

Looks as though a couple of your kernel configuration parameters don't even exist for that kernel. Actually there never is a CONFIG_USB_SUSPEND, but CONFIG_USB_AUTOSUSPEND shows up around kernel 5.1. There never is a CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME.

Answer (score 1):

Your currently running Linux kernel has a configuration (`config`) file in `/boot/`. The filename looks like */boot/config-**. Run the following to find the exact name.

```
ls -l /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

In there you can find whether those configuration parameters have been enabled or not.

Comment: There's no config-* files in `/boot/`

Comment: Your kernel version looks non-standard for Ubuntu. Google says https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/installing-python-3-6-on-jetson-tx2-under-balenaos/75404/4 Do you run this on AARCH64? Is it BalenaOS?